# Jest test if App renders produces Unable to find an element with the text: Profil

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, rendering

I have little to no knowledge of Jest. How can test whether the App component gets rendered? My test cases fail

console log:
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: Profil. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

```
      26 |         const { getByText } = render(<App />);
    > 27 |         const homeLink = getByText('Profil');
         |                          ^
      28 |         expect(homeLink).toBeInTheDocument();
      29 |     });
      30 | });
```

app.test.js

```js
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from '../App';
import React from 'react';
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from '@cfaester/enzyme-adapter-react-18';
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Navigate,
  Outlet
} from "react-router-dom";

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });


describe('App', () => {
    // let wrapper;
    // beforeEach(() => (wrapper = shallow(<App />)));
    

    test('renders correctly', () => {
        // expect(wrapper.containsMatchingElement(<App />)).toEqual(true);

        const { getByText } = render(<App />);
        const homeLink = getByText('Profil');
        expect(homeLink).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
});
```

App.js

```
import Users from './pages/User/Users';
import Home from './pages/Home/Home';
import AddUser from './pages/CreateUser/AddUser';
import Login from './pages/Login/Login'
import RestartPassword from './pages/Login/RestartPassword';
import UserNavi from './pages/User/UserNavi'
import GroupNavi from './pages/GroupDisplay/GroupNavi'
import GroupIdNavi from './pages/GroupDisplay/GroupIdNavi'
import AddGroup from './pages/CreateGroup/AddGroup';
import ChildrenNavi from './pages/Children/ChildrenNavi';
import AddChild from './pages/CreateChild/AddChild';
import ChildNavi from './pages/Children/ChildNavi';
import LoginService from "./pages/Login/LoginService"
import UserChildNavi from "./pages/UserChild/UserChildNavi"
import EditUserNavi from './pages/EditUser/EditUserNavi';
import MessageNavi from './pages/messages/MessageNavi';
import SendMessageNavi from './pages/messages/SendMessageNavi';
import SentMessageNavi from './pages/messages/SentMessageNavi';
import ReadMessageNavi from './pages/messages/ReadMessageNavi';
import GalleryNavi from "./pages/gallery/GalleryNavi";
import GaleriaNavi from "./pages/gallery/GaleriaNavi";
import StatusMessageNavi from './pages/messages/StatusMessageNavi';
import ViewMessageNavi from './pages/messages/ViewMessageNavi';
import KnowledgeNavi from './pages/gallery/KnowledgeNavi';
import ViewGalleryNavi from './pages/gallery/ViewGalleryNavi';
import AddGalleryNavi from './pages/gallery/AddGalleryNavi';

import React, {useState} from 'react';

import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Navigate,
  Outlet
} from "react-router-dom";
import ChangePassword from './pages/Login/ChangePassword';



function App() {
  const [navVisible, showNavbar] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <navbar visible={navVisible} show={showNavbar} />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/home" element={<Navigate to="/home" />} />
          <Route
            path="/home"
            element={
              <div className={!navVisible ? "page" : "page page-with-navbar"}>
                <h1>Profil</h1>
              </div>
            }
          />

          <Route path="/">
            <Route index element={<Login />}></Route>
          </Route>
          <Route path="restart-password">
            <Route index element={<RestartPassword />}></Route>
          </Route>
          <Route path="change/:token">
            <Route index element={<ChangePassword />}></Route>
          </Route>
          <Route path="users" element={<PrivateOutlet />}>
            <Route index element={<Users />}></Route>
          </Route>
          <Route path="add-user" element={<PrivateOutlet />}>
            <Route index element={<AddUser />}></Route>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/home" element={<PrivateOutlet />}>
            <Route index element={<Home />}></Route>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/home/restart-password" element={<PrivateOutlet />}>
            <Route index element={<RestartPassword />}></Route>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/user/:id" element={<PrivateOutlet />}>
            <Route index element={<UserNavi />}></Route>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/groups" element={<PrivateOutlet />}>
            <Route index element={<GroupNavi />}></Route>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/group/:id" element={<PrivateOutlet />}>
            <Route index element={<GroupIdNavi />}></Route>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/add-group" element={<PrivateOutlet />}>
            <Route index element={<AddGroup />}></Route>
          </Route>
          <Route path="children" element={<PrivateOutlet />}>
            <Route index element={<ChildrenNavi />}></Route>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/add-child" element={<PrivateOutlet />}>
            <Route index element={<AddChild />}></Route>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/child/:id" element={<PrivateOutlet />}>
            <Route index element={<ChildNavi />}></Route>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/user/:id/child" element={<PrivateOutlet />}>
            <Route index element={<UserChildNavi />}></Route>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/user/:id/edit" element={<PrivateOutlet />}>
            <Route index element={<EditUserNavi />}></Route>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/Message" element={<PrivateOutlet />}>
            <Route index element={<MessageNavi />}></Route>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/SendMessage" element={<PrivateOutlet />}>
            <Route index element={<SendMessageNavi />}></Route>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/SentMessage" element={<PrivateOutlet />}>
            <Route index element={<SentMessageNavi />}></Route>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/ReadMessage/:id" element={<PrivateOutlet />}>
            <Route index element={<ReadMessageNavi />}></Route>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/AddGallery" element={<PrivateOutlet />}>
            <Route index element={<AddGalleryNavi />}></Route>
          </Route>
          <Route path='/Gallery' element={<PrivateOutlet />}>
            <Route index element={<GalleryNavi/>}></Route>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/StatusMessage/:id" element={<PrivateOutlet />}>
            <Route index element={<StatusMessageNavi />}></Route>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/ViewMessage/:id" element={<PrivateOutlet />}>
            <Route index element={<ViewMessageNavi />}></Route>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/Knowledge" element={<PrivateOutlet />}>
            <Route index element={<KnowledgeNavi />}></Route>
          </Route>
          <Route path='/ViewGallery/:id' element={<PrivateOutlet />}>
            <Route index element={<ViewGalleryNavi/>}></Route>
          </Route>
          <Route path='/AddGallery' element={<PrivateOutlet />}>
            <Route index element={<AddGalleryNavi/>}></Route>
          </Route>
          <Route path='/Galeria' element={<PrivateOutlet />}>
            <Route index element={<GaleriaNavi/>}></Route>
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

function PrivateOutlet() {
  const auth = useAuth();
  return auth ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/" />;
}

function useAuth() {
  return LoginService.isLoggedIn();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use test id's when possible. So in your App.js I would write the h1 tag like this:

```
 <div className={!navVisible ? "page" : "page page-with-navbar"}>
                <h1  data-testid={'someTestId'}>Profil</h1>
              </div>
```

Then in your app.test.js:

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import React from 'react';


describe('App test: ', () => {

    test('h1 renders', async () => {

          render(<App/>);

          expect(await screen.findByTestId('someTestId')).toBeInTheDocument();
    });

});
```

Documentation: https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro/

Comment: console error     Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="someTestId"]                                                                                                                                                 

i added your lines:
                <h1 data-testid={'someTestId'}>Profil</h1>
and 

    test('h1 renders', async () => {

          render(<App/>);

          expect(await screen.findByTestId('someTestId')).toBeInTheDocument();
    });

Comment: Hi sorry I didn't get back to your comment. Did you find a solution?

Comment: hi. no, i did not

Comment: Okay, can you update your code to what it looks like now, after trying my solution? Just to make sure you added the test id correctly in your h1 tag. Also try and run the following:

expect(render(<App/>) and see in the terminal if you can find your h1 tag